# Changing width of Fixed navbar and keeping Collapse element and adding logo/image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying to change the width of my navbar which is fixed and also has a navbar-collapse property that i want to keep when screen size changes.

I also added in the Bootstrap i am using for this page, so at the moment with the code below, the navbar is fixed but is full width, it collapses when you change to mobile site, so the only thing i want is to change the width from full width so that there is atleast 30% open space on either side of the navbar so it will be centred to the page.

and also adding a logo/image to the navbar only when its collapsed

Hope you can help me!

```
 <html>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
.navbar-nav.nav-justified > li{float:none; }

.navbar{
    background-color:white;
    font-family: Amatic SC;
    border:none;
    font-size: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align:center;  
        }

.navbar:hover,
.navbar:active {
     color: black;
     transition: background-color 0.3s ease-oin,
         color 0.3s ease-out;
        }

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
       color: black;
    }

@media (max-width: 981px) {
.navbar-left,.navbar-right {
     float: none !important;
        }

.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
        }

.navbar-collapse {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
        }

.navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0%;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
        }

.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
        }

.navbar-nav {
     float: none!important;
      margin-top: 7.5px;
        }

.navbar-nav>li {
     float: none;    
       }

.navbar-nav>li>a {
     padding-top: 10px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;                                               
        }

.collapse.in{
     display:block !important;
      }
    }
</style>
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" "col-xs- col-xs-offset-0 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"  >
 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="text-align:center" >
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-justified">
    <li id="scrollDetails"><a href="#Details">Details</a></li>
    <li id="scrollDirections"><a href="#directions">Directions</a></li>
    <li id="navRsvp"><a href="#rsvp">RSVP</a></li>
    <li id="scrollBucket"><a href="#gBook">Bucket List</a></li>
    <li id="scrollAccommodation"><a href="#Accom">Accommodation</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>  
 </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the width and centrally align your code in the media queries for the expected behaviour in mobile view.

You have to add the following css:

```
@media (max-width: 981px) {
      .navbar {
        width: 30%;
        margin: auto;
      }
}
```

Refer code:

```css
.navbar-nav.nav-justified > li {
  float: none;
}
.navbar {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Amatic SC;
  border: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar:hover,
.navbar:active {
  color: black;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-oin, color 0.3s ease-out;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: black;
}
@media (max-width: 981px) {
  .navbar {
    width: 30%;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .navbar-left,
  .navbar-right {
    float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0%;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin-top: 7.5px;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .collapse.in {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top col-xs-offset-0 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="text-align:center">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-justified">
      <li id="scrollDetails"><a href="#Details">Details</a>
      </li>
      <li id="scrollDirections"><a href="#directions">Directions</a>
      </li>
      <li id="navRsvp"><a href="#rsvp">RSVP</a>
      </li>
      <li id="scrollBucket"><a href="#gBook">Bucket List</a>
      </li>
      <li id="scrollAccommodation"><a href="#Accom">Accommodation</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it works however on the mobile view the collapsed navbar icon in the middle of the page instead of the far right corner and the menu items are cut off vertically. @nashcheez